# No more hovering to edit tags above 10k!

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Just discovered a change to editing tags above 10k rep - there is now an 'Edit' button instead of having to hover on an invisible space.

[image]

Thanks SE for the change!

Comment: This topic on Meta.SO: [Can we hide the inline tag edit button, please? This is distracting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374024/4642212).

Comment: This is likely done to support mobile device users with a touch screen, which have no hover.

Comment: For those who have installed my [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js), I have just pushed a change to display the Edit link only on mouseover.